# Causing a thread to stop while stuck within a while loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, loops

Is is possible to stop a thread prematurely when it is stuck inside a while loop? Below is my sample code, which runs correctly, since each time it calls `loop_thread` it will check to see if the `threading.Event()` flag is set. When attempting to run the code for a file that processes information much longer than each second, there is no way to stop the entire function from continuing its execution until the next iteration. For example, if I run `dld_img_thread`, it takes about 5 minutes to complete its execution and recheck the while loop to see if should proceed. What I want to have happen is kill the `dld_img_thread` at a time shorter than 5 minutes (e.g. 1 minute). I don't care if the data is lost, just that the thread stops before the function finishes execution. Thank you

```
import threading, time, pythoncom, read_mt0
import powerfail_debugport_reader as pf_dbg_rdr
import powerfail_firmware_downloader as pf_fwdld


def loop_thread(thread_name, thread_event):
    loopCnt = 0
    print "\nstarting {}".format(thread_name)
    print "is {0} alive? {1}\n".format(thread_name, L00P_thread.is_alive())
    while not thread_event.is_set():
        print("value of loopCnt = {}".format(loopCnt))
        loopCnt += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('stopping {}\n'.format(thread_name))

def image_dld(thread_name, thread_event):
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
    print "\nstarting {}".format(thread_name)
    print "is {0} alive? {1}\n".format(thread_name, dld_img_thread.is_alive())
    while not thread_event.is_set():
        pf_fwdld.power_fail_test()
    print('stopping {}'.format(thread_name))

def debug_port_thread(thread_name, thread_event):
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
    print "\nstarting {}".format(thread_name)
    print "is {0} alive? {1}\n".format(thread_name, debug_thread.is_alive())
    pf_dbg_rdr.debug_port_reader()
    print('\nstopping {}'.format(thread_name))

def main():
    global L00P_thread, debug_thread
    pf_dbg_rdr.samurai_event = threading.Event()

    L00P_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop_thread, \
        args=('L00P_thread', pf_dbg_rdr.samurai_event))

    dld_img_thread = threading.Thread(target=image_dld, \
        args=('image_download', pf_dbg_rdr.samurai_event))

    debug_thread = threading.Thread(target=debug_port_thread, \
        args=('debug_port_reader', pf_dbg_rdr.samurai_event))

    L00P_thread.start()
    dld_img_thread.start()
    debug_thread.start()
    debug_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('processes stopped')
    print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a second variable in your while condition that you can change once your timeout is reached.

For example:

```
shouldRun = True
while not thread_event.is_set() and shouldRun:
    print("value of loopCnt = {}".format(loopCnt))
    loopCnt += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if loopCnt > 60: shouldRun = False
```

would stop after 60 iterations (about 60 seconds given you sleep for 1 second on each iteration).

Comment: that works fine for the looping thread, but for the other thread which as explained, this process would not work. I set a flag in an outside function, which is supposed to stop the other thread, but it will only work after the entire function has complete its execution.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't spot that. My fault for trying to do too many things at once.